# Instagram XPath in Selenium Won't Work? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram

Im creating an Instagram bot in Selenium basically to like certain comments with other Instagram accounts, but Im unable to .click() on the xpath of Instagram's heart in the comment section of a certain comment. I really just need the correct xpath of the heart in Instagram's comment section, and I'll be done with this.

````
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib

Link = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CCZDF7YH5Yb/c/17958711199328488/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('username') #Changed for the purpose of making this thread
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('password')
Login = "//button[@type='submit']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Login).submit()
sleep(1)
#Logs into Instagram
print ('Logged In')

NotNow = "//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(NotNow).click()
#Clicks Pop Up
print ('Close Pop Up')

#ISSUE is Below

#CommentHeart = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/svg' #THIS XPATH doesn't work?
driver.get(Link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/div[2]/ul/div/li/div/span/div/button/svg'))) #THIS XPATH doesn't work
element.click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath(CommentHeart).click()
print ('Likes Comment')```

This is the xpath I've been using, that doesn't work.
```//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/div[2]/ul/div/li/div/span/div/button/svg```
````

Comment: Just a little trick i have learned ... if u take a full path, chances are that things wont break that easily ... also if u take an xpath, try go to the root, if its crashing to see where a mistake shall be .... also, instead of driver waits, use time.sleep, just to keep things simple and later make them sleep til ltheycsre clickable and stuff (if u make it wait like 5 seconds and u can see its clickable, but it will crash, that means u have problem with xpath ... many time i have seen a code where person just did wrong the wait part and was struggling to make it work ... anyways GL in coding !

Answer (score 2):

I used the xpath below to find the like button and it works for me

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[1]/'
                                         'span[1]/button').click()
```

from what I can see in your code is that you have

```
/section[1]/span[1]/button/svg
```

but it should be just

```
/section[1]/span[1]/button
```

since you want to click on the button and not svg

Comment: Appreciate this, I ended up using ```//span/div/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']``` but I'll try using this as well.